# How to create a directed scale free network in python with special average degree?

Tags: python, networking, networkx

I found this function in networkX:

```
scale_free_graph(n, alpha=0.41, beta=0.54, gamma=0.05, 
                delta_in=0.2, delta_out=0, 
                create_using=None, seed=None)
```

but I don't understand how can I able to change these parameter to have a directed scale free graph by special mean degree (for example: mean degree = 4)

Comment: Are you specifically interested in scale free graphs, or in a random graph with mean degree of N? There are many other ways to generate random graphs - see https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generators.html#module-networkx.generators.random_graphs

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can build random graph with special average degree. I want to compare some features between random graphs and scalr free graph, for this reason I need to have both in the same mean degree. But I cannot able to build a scale free graph with special mean degree! This is my quesion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of adding a node and an edge is Alpha + Gamma. The probability of adding just an edge is Beta. Therefore, if you'd like to get an average degree of N, the ratio between beta and (alpha + gamma) should be N-1. In other words:

```
beta / (alpha+gamma) == degree - 1
```

For gamma of 0.05, and an average degree of 4, use the following values:

- Beta: .75
- Gamma: 0.05
- Alpha: 1-Beta-Gamma

Here's a chart that shows the mean degree for gamma = 0.05 and different values of beta.

[image]

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer, and let me know if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

When I use nx.scale_free_graph to generate a scale-free network, I find that there exists more than one directed edge with the same direction between two nodes. Is there any method that can guarantee only one directed edge between two nodes?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34649060)